# what are the equivalent of these various sql table in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax

SQL tables:

sys.types
sysobjects
syscolumns
sysindexes
INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

Can you also help me convert this to oracle syntax

```
DECLARE @tableUpdateCount tinyint
set @tableUpdateCount = 0
/* 
* CALCDETL.ALIAS - 1
*/
if exists (select * from syscolumns where id = (select id from sysobjects where name = 'ABC' and type = 'U') and name = 'ALIAS' and xusertype = (select user_type_id from sys.types where name = 'nvarchar') and prec = 20)
begin
    set @tableUpdateCount = @tableUpdateCount + 1
    print ' '
    print '1.  ABC.ALIAS exists'
end
```

are there any tools out there that can easily convert sql-to-oracle syntax?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will definately help you out. It's free.

- [Oracle's SQL Developer Migration Workbench](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/index.html)

Btw, for converting your `SQL syntax-> Oracle syntax`, you must first, go through this comparison.

- [SQL Syntax differences between Oracle and MS-SQL](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_news/2005_12_16_sql_syntax_differences.htm)

Comment: can you please point me to the right download link for oracle's sql developer migration workbench? when i click the link above it redirects me to the home page. Thanks

Comment: Even though it ok, link only answers are generally not helpful. Copy the relevant information here and add the link as additional info for people.

Answer (score 5):

```
sysobjects  <-> USER_OBJECTS
syscolumns  <-> USER_TAB_COLUMNS
sysindexes <-> USER_INDEXES
```

you can use ALL/DBA instead of USER depending on the scope you like to search in (and your Role in the Database)

See the [Reference](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96536/toc.htm) for more Info.

And Check: [Oracle Functions Pl/SQL](http://psoug.org/reference/functions.html) for the conversion

Answer (score 1):

```
set ServerOutPut on;

DECLARE
     tableUpdateCount number(1) := 0;
     Id number(5);
/* 
* CALCDETL.ALIAS - 1
*/
Begin
select id into Id from syscolumns where id = (select id from sysobjects where name = 'ABC' and type = 'U') and name = 'ALIAS' and xusertype = (select user_type_id from sys.types where name = 'nvarchar') and prec = 20);

    tableUpdateCount := tableUpdateCount + 1; 
    dbms_outPut.Put_line('');
    dbms_outPut.Put_line('1.  ABC.ALIAS exists'); 
Exception
    when No_Data_found then
          dbms_outPut.Put_line('ABC.ALIAS not found');
End;
```